# How to get all posted files at once using fineUploader?

Tags: fine-uploader

I have a fineuploader that allows multiple files to be uploaded in MVC web app.

Example:
Suppose I upload 3 files 5MB, 20MB, 1MB

I expect 3 files to arrive in the controller in single call but they are not.
I want to iterate all 3 files (array) and process

**Question 1**: Is there a way to get all 3 files at once in the server?

```
[HttpPost]
public FineUploaderResult UploadFile(FineUpload upload)
{
   //upload contains only one file at a time
   //for second file it gets call again even though I submit only once
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  Fine Uploader sends each file in a separate request.  This is not currently configurable.    If you need to tie your files together, you can easily do that by passing common parameters with each file via the [`params` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options.html#request-option_1), or the [`setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods.html).  Sever-side, you can look for this common parameter in each upload POST request and deal with the files accordingly.

Comment: If I submit 3 files 1MB 50MB and 2KB. Should I get success for file 3, then file 1 and lastly file2 as large file will take long time to upload. What is the definite way to associate each success with the corresponding file? Since my files goes to a queue, I need to update queue db once I get success. I don't want a situation where I treat first success for file 1 but it will be for file 3.

Comment: Other question: All 3 files get posted asynchronously? In my example 2KB file has to wait for 50MB file to finish it's submission since 50MB file was #2 and 2KB file was #3

Comment: All three files will be sent at once, in different requests.  If you want your server to know when all files are complete, you can send an Ajax request once this is clear from the client. You can easily determine when all files are complete client side using fine Uploader's callbacks.  See the example at the end of the status doc page for an example: http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/statistics-and-status-updates.html