# Fine-uploader upload all files together

Tags: php, upload, fine-uploader

I notice that fine-uploader upload one file per request. Is possible to upload all files with one single request? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all posted files at once using fineUploader?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056720/how-to-get-all-posted-files-at-once-using-fineuploader)

Comment: Thanks, yes is the same question. However, is not good this way. I need to send file with also a form data, and each files submit all data again and again...